# IMO 2003 /G1: Show that $PQ=QR$ if and only if the bisectors of $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ADC$ are concurrent with $AC$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, projective-geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral. Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $D$ to the lines $BC$, $CA$, $AB$, respectively. Show that $PQ=QR$ if and only if the bisectors of $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ADC$ are concurrent with $AC$.

Here's the diagram:

[image]

I want to use projective geo .

**My Progress** : It is very known that $P,Q,R$ are collinear[simson line]

Now, here's a lemma.

**Lemma**: Given a cyclic quad $ABCD$, the angle bisectors $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ADC$ are concurrent with $AC$ if and only if $ABCD$ is harmonic .

**Proof** : if $ABCD$ is harmonic, then $(A,C;B,D)=-1 \implies \frac {BA}{BC}=\frac {DA}{DC} $ , now applying the angle bisector theorem , we are done.

We can go backwards for proving the other direction.

---

So, the rephrased question is:

> Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral. Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be the feet of the perpendiculars from $D$ to the lines $BC$, $CA$, $AB$, respectively. Show that $Q$ is the midpoint of $PR$  if and only if $ABCD$ is harmonic:

Now , since , I am asked to use Projective geo , I am planning on showing $(P,R;Q,P_{\infty})=-1$ . Now , I can get  $P_{\infty}$ when I consider a line parallel to simson line but I am not able to proceed on taking which line. I took a line parallel to $PR$ through $D$, but not able to proceed..

Comment: I have done this problem using sin , you can try it that way, but I haven't tried projective geo though.. ( +1 for your effort )

Comment: The exact line you want parallel to $PQR$ is $BX$ where $X$ is the point of intersection of $DQ$ and the circle. (this is the first proposition in the simson's line section in Evan Chen's geometry book)

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a solution using projective geometry? I remember I solved this using complex co-ordinates back in my olympiad days.

Comment: umm..yes, but you can post our complex solution too .

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 , I am not able to proceed can give your solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend $DQ$ to meet the circle at $X$.Then, BX would be parallel to the simson line as mentioned in the comment.

If part:
Now,let $BX$ meet $AC$ at $Y$.Take perspectivity at $B$ onto line $AC$ to show that $(Y,Q,A,C)$ harmonic.Now,take perspectivity at $X$ onto the circle to show that $ABCD$ is harmonic.
The other direction can be proved similarly.

Comment: Thanks I got it.